# How to check for paid chrome license in Android app that has been put on Chrome Store using ARC?

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

I'm starting to port an Android app over to the Chrome App store using the ARC tool.  The first app is a free one but I'd like to put a paid app on the Chrome store as well and I have 2 questions.

1. Is checking for the license mandatory or just a best practice so you apps are not pirated?
2. Does anyone had a good sample code of performing the license check for chrome, written in java for an Android app.

thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you mean, what license check do you want to do?  There is no support for cross PlayStore/WebStore licensing, and Chrome Web Store apps don't have a license server for paid apps AFAIK.

Comment: If a user has bought a paid chrome app, it seems your app should check and see if the user is has a license.  I imagine this is to stop unauthorized copies of your app working.   Here's the google link about the topic.  https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/check_for_payment  I wanted to know if this is a mandatory requirement or just good practice and how would I do this for an Android app that I am porting over to the Chrome store.

Answer (score 0):

> Is checking for the license mandatory or just a best practice so you apps are not pirated?

It is not mandatory.  And in a packaged app (which all ARC apps are), it is difficult to do this securely, as noted at https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/check_for_payment: "Although you can use the API in packaged apps and extensions, it's more difficult for them to use the license server securely"

> Does anyone had a good sample code of performing the license check for chrome, written in java for an Android app.

There is no exposed API to do a license check in this manner with ARC currently.

The more common monetization strategy so far for ARC apps has been ads on free apps, so any special work for paid apps has not been prioritized.